# subverion 1.8.5 compile error on mac os x 10.9 cmdline.c

Tags: macos, svn, makefile

In compiling subversion 1.8.5 on Mac OS X 10.9, I run into this problem when trying to 'make' from source code.

> subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.c: In function 'svn_cmdline_create_auth_baton':
>   subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.c:630: error: 'SVN_AUTH_PARAM_GNOME_KEYRING_UNLOCK_PROMPT_FUNC' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.c:630: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.c:630: error: for each function it appears in.)
>   make: *** [subversion/libsvn_subr/cmdline.lo] Error 1

I recently upgraded to Xcode 5, should Xcode 5 on OS 10.9 be running in connection with subversion 1.7 or 1.8, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: What do you mean "svn command isn't working"?  You are compiling it?  Anyway try macports.

Comment: after upgrading to xcode 5, this is what I get: `svn -version
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libneon.27.dylib
  Referenced from: /Developer/usr/bin/svn
  Reason: image not found` so the paths got changed; and i'm trying to upgrade svn 1.8.5 on mac os 10.9, unless I'm trying to do something I shouldn't for this version of the os.  [Here](http://samoldak.com/updating-to-svn-1-8-for-mac-os-x-10-8/) are the instructions I tried to follow as well.

Comment: You are wasting your time.  This is the key to the error: `/Developer/usr/bin/svn`.  That isn't Xcode 5.

Comment: settle down, I never said the problem is xcode 5, I want to upgrade to svn 1.8.5 and I in compiling from source, I get an error. I am looking for help on getting around that error, or learning more about what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Can you tell me why you have a `/Developer` directory at all?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177699/using-svn-1-8-3-with-xcode-5) answers my question about which version to use with xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought this was a problem building the SWIG bindings.  We see a very similar issue with SWIG bindings.  My original answer is below with that info (leaving it since some people might find this entry when looking for that error message for that).

However, on looking more carefully at the errors I see that you're having an actual problem building Subversion itself.  This is a different problem.  Specifically you appear to have GNOME Keyring installed and it was detected by the configure.  However, the problem is there is a mismatch between the code that enables the constant you're getting an error about (checking for platform) and the constant that enables the use of that (checking for GNOME Keyring being found).

You should be able to build if you pass `--with-gnome-keyring=no` to configure.

**SWIG**

There is a known issue with Subversion 1.8.x on OSX.  SWIG bindings won't build properly with the pre-generated interfaces.  If you install SWIG you can still build successfully by doing the following:

```
make extraclean
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

You can skip the `make extraclean` if you're starting with a fresh tarball.  Note that extraclean will remove the config.nice file so you'll need to manually pass any options to configure again rather than using config.nice.

If you're interested in the gory details the details on how this is being fixed here:
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/201311.mbox/%3C528D264A.4090305%40reser.org%3E

The commit on trunk that actually fixes it is here:
http://svn.apache.org/r1543961

This fix will hopefully be included in 1.8.6 so that it isn't an issue anymore.

Comment: Brilliant! Your suggestion worked perfectly.  Yes, I am interested in the gory details. On a Mac OS system it is not unheard of to have some app requiring use of GNOME Keyring, right?

Comment: It's possible.  The problem is that when we build the public interface we don't know if the build found gnome support because we don't have the svn_private_config.h file (where SVN_HAVE_GNOME_KEYRIN is defined).  So in svn_auth.h we check for Windows and Mac and exclude the interface definitions.  The whole auth api is a disaster.