# Xcode 6.x Yosemite not syncing properly to svn from previous projects

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, osx-yosemite

Is this happening to others out there?

Ever since my team has upgraded to Yosemite and Xcode 6, 6.1, 6.2 we can not interact with our existing svn via the Xcode UI very well. The status icons do work, but seem sluggish, and we can not update or commit using the mouse right click feature for individual classes.

We can do diffs, commits, and updates via the terminal just fine.

I reverted my brew svn 1.8 installation back to 1.7.19(which is what the rest of the teams is using) because it wouldn't work at all with the Xcode UI.

What I have tried:

Several examples on the web and on SO on how to install svn 1.8.x and get it to work with Xcode. Others just talk about linking svn files, and toolchains, each of which stop any functionality with Xcode.

[svn 1.8 working with xcode](https://gist.github.com/PeterLi/0146930c9e04c962afe9)

[Using svn 1.8.3 with Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177699/using-svn-1-8-3-with-xcode-5)

I've also tried checking out a fresh copy of the branch using the UI. It checks it out successfully, but doesn't interact any better.

I have Xcode 6.2 installed with Xcode 6.2 dev tools, so that should not be the issue.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for an answer, https://gist.github.com/PeterLi/0146930c9e04c962afe9 certainly provides a correct set of instructions. We've used it every time we upgraded Xcode (6.1, 6.2, etc.). Make sure you follow the instructions fully including at the very bottom of that post.

Comment: Please provide actual instructions credited to the source you mentioned. If the link goes dead, this post won't help anyone. :)

Comment: This very useful link is widely referenced by others on stackoverflow and elsewhere. I wouldn't want to create an impression that its content is of my own design.

Comment: This is a good guide for updating to SVN 1.8 but that is not my issue. I reverted back to 1.7.xx when I could see there was no improvement.  I have tried these steps and it does not work. Xcode still ships with with svn 1.7.xx so it should work well with my 1.7.xx client but it does not. Xcode has not worked properly with our svn since version 6 was released. Version 5. worked flawlessly. We cant event trust the status icons 100%. We have to rely on the terminal.